# Merging two json files using python

Tags: python

I'm new to python, I want to merge two JSON files
there should not be any duplicate:
if the values and name are same then I will add both the keys and maintain a single record, otherwise, I will keep the record

File 1:

```
[   {
        "key": 1,
    "name": "test",
        "value": "NY"
    },
    {
        "key": 1,
    "name": "test",
        "value": "CA"
    },
    {
        "key": 1,
    "name": "test",
        "value": "MA"
    },
  {
    "key": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "value": "MA"
  }
]
```

File 2:

```
[   {
        "key": 1,
    "name": "test",
        "value": "NJ"
    },
    {
        "key": 1,
    "name": "test",
        "value": "CA"
    },
    {
        "key": 1,
    "name": "test",
        "value": "TX"
    },
  {
    "key": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "value": "MA"
  }
]
```

and the merged file output should be:

```
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "value": "NY"
  },
  {
    "key": 3,
    "name": "test",
    "value": "MA"
  },
  {
    "key": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "value": "NJ"
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "name": "test",
    "value": "CA"
  },
  {
    "key": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "value": "TX"
  }
]
```

order of the record does not matter.

I have tried several approaches, like merging the files and then iterating over then, parsing both files separately but I'm facing issues, being new to python.

Comment: It is very confusing that your `'key'` is the value you want to store (and which you sum in case of duplicates) and your `'value'` is the unique key by which to identify an entry. Usually it is the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
f1 = [   {
        "key": 1,
        "value": "NY"
    },
    {
        "key": 1,
        "value": "CA"
    },
    {
        "key": 1,
        "value": "MA"
    }
]

f2 = [   {
        "key": 1,
        "value": "NJ"
    },
    {
        "key": 1,
        "value": "CA"
    },
    {
        "key": 1,
        "value": "TX"
    }
]
check = [i["value"] for i in f1]  #check list to see if the value already exist in f1.
for i in f2:
    if i['value'] not in check:
        f1.append(i)

print(f1)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'value': 'NY', 'key': 1}, {'value': 'CA', 'key': 1}, {'value': 'MA', 'key': 1}, {'value': 'NJ', 'key': 1}, {'value': 'TX', 'key': 1}]
```

Comment: this will not sum up the keys if the value is present in f1. If f1 and f2 have the record, then I want to merge sum up the keys value.